# For loop running only once after my while loop

Tags: python, for-loop

I am just a beginner in python and stuck in this code.
My while loop is executing perfectly but for loop is running only once.
Can someone please help?
Following is my code:

```
import os
import json
import csv
import pandas as pd
os.chdir("C:/Users/lchavan/Test 4")
df= "C:/Users/lchavan/Test 4"
dir_list = os.listdir(df)
for filename in os.listdir(df):
    with open(filename) as json_file:
        data = json.load(json_file)
        print(filename)
    i = 0
    while i >= 0:
        x = data[0]['created']
        if i < len(x):
            y = x[i]
            for k,v in y.items():
                if k == 'geomenter code hereetry':
                    z = y['geometry']['coordinates']
                    print (z)
        i+=1
        pass
```

Comment: which `for` loop? You have two

Comment: I'm not sure what the intent of the code is, but it looks like the `while` part would be stuck with ever increasing values of `i`, and not doing anything except `i += 1` after `i` reaches (and exceeds) `len(x)`.

Comment: Also, is this code meant to run forever? I don't see an ending condition for the while

Answer (score 0):

You may want to change your while loop:

```py
...
i = 0
while i < len(x):
    ...
```

And you could probably do simpler, replacing the while loop by:

```py
x = data[0]['created']
for y in x:
    ...
```